# Parsing JSON data and checking if array is empty

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get an array from a JSON object, and check if it's empty, but it's giving me problems.
HTML:

```
<p id="r"></p>
```

JS:

```
var r = document.getElementById('r');

var obj = {
    "_id": "4345356",
    "title": "sdfsf",
    "data": []
};

obj = JSON.parse(obj);

function isEmpty(a) {
    if (typeof a === 'undefined' || a.length == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

r.innerHTML = isEmpty(obj.data);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXc2E/). What did I miss? Thanks!

Comment: `obj` already is a JavaScript object, why do you want to `parse()` it again ?

Comment: JSON.parse() takes a string, your "obj" is not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to parse the `obj`. It's already an object.

remove this line

```
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, it appears you don't have a need what whatsoever for

```
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

Finally to check emptiness of an array is easy, in your case, do this:

```
r.innerHTML = !obj.data.length;
```

or

```
r.innerHTML = obj.data.length === 0;
```

But if you really have a need to define a function for this purpose, then the following should be enough:

```
function isEmpty(a) {
    return a && !a.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line: `obj = JSON.parse(obj);` I have updated the fiddle.